# Parameters for loading PDF files in MuPDF with different resolution

Tags: windows, batch

I'm running MuPDF in Windows 8.1. It works fine for the most part (it allows file association). But there are no CFG/INI files for manipulating parameters and no app-specific option menu in the window. That has to be done from the command line.

The tedious part comes in for the default resolution (72 dpi). Naturally some files are rendered smaller than I would prefer for viewing. The command syntax (from the Run window) is as follows:

```
>(PATH to mupdf.exe) -r** (PATH to file.pdf)
```

I'd like to set up a batch file that performs the same function as the above command, except I want an option to change the resolution. This is what I've written so far.

```
@echo off
start C:\Users\name\mupdf\mupdf.exe %1 (this last option seems to be redundant)
(Do I need a CLS here?)
exit
```

This opens a window that lets me pick the PDF I want to open. So that part works fine. I just need to know how to change the `-r` flag.

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation I found in the package [here](http://code.google.com/p/mupdf/downloads/detail?name=mupdf-1.3-windows.zip&can=2&q=) (man\mupdf.txt):

> OPTIONS
>
> -r resolution
>
> Changes the initial zoom level, specified as the  resolution  in dpi.  The default value is 72.

So, your batch should be something like this:

```
start C:\Users\name\mupdf\mupdf.exe -r 96 (path to file)
```

Where `96` is the desired resolution.